# Key differences between Plex and XBMC

Tags: mediaplayer

As I understood it [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/) was forked from [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) as some people was unhappy with the slow development off the Mac integration.

Now when both applications are available on OS X what are the main differences regarding:

- Features
- Stability
- Support
- Addons